# PDO return objects ids in keys

Tags: php, pdo

hey i have array with returned keys

```
$temp = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

my result looks like this:

```
[0] => [
    'id' = 11,
    'title' => 't1'
]

[1] => [
    'id' = 12,
    'title' => 't2'
]
```

if i want to return ids as key i call something like this:

```
$temp = array_map(function($v){return $v[0];}, $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

and my resoult looks like this:

```
[11] => [
    'title' => 't1'
]

[12] => [
    'title' => 't2'
]
```

how to return array of objects by ID? when i do this i dont have methods in object...

```
$temp = array_map(function($v){return $v[0];}, $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_CLASS));
```

Comment: Can you clarify how your result array should look like? "it does not appear" is not really helpful

Comment: `array_combine( array_column( $results, 'id' ), $results );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will do a bit easier code like below:-

```
$fianl_array = array_combine(array_column($temp,'id'),$temp);
```

Final Output:-

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [title] => t1
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [title] => t2
        )

)
```

Reference:-

[array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

[array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Answer (score 1):

Using foreach:

```
foreach($input as $k=>$v){
    $output[$v['id']] = array('title'=>$v['title']);
}
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had to add this as an answer as I believe it's the shortest way of doing this, using [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) with a third parameter which is the key you want the data indexed by.  If you use null as the second parameter, it will index all the data by 'id', you could instead use 'title' and this will only index the title columns by ID...

```
$output = array_column($temp,null,'id');
```

Which gives...

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [title] => t1
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [title] => t2
        )

)
```